# Serve files privately with JSP/Tomcat?

Tags: file, jsp, tomcat, private

I am writing a JSP app which should allow users to log in (authenticate against a PostgreSQL database with a simple username and password check), and upload photos.  The images should be private in that they can only be accessed by the user while logged in.  A copy of the image URL should not work after logout.  How can this be done with Tomcat/JSP?

I do not want to store BLOBs in my database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use servlet filters. 
Let's say you have url like /images/ where all your images are stored, so using filters you can check whether the session for this user is alive or not.

Some examples:
[example 1](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial)
[example 2](http://uaihebert.com/user-authentication-filterservlet/)

Answer (score 1):

You start by storing the images in an unaccessible folder on your server.

Any time a user requests a specific image - you redirect the user to another servlet that accepts requests for images.

This servlet will check the session to see if the user is authenticated and that it's the same user that requests the image and that the image is accessible for that user.

Once that the servlet authenticates the user and the request - it copies the image to a temporary accessible folder and redirects the user to that image.

You can add improvements like checking if the image is already in the temp folder before copying and a "clean job" that runs every hour and removes files from the temporary folder if the file was copied more than one hour ago (you can "touch" any file you copy) etc.

Two more points:

- By using [forward()](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html) (vs. `sendRedirect()`) the user will not be able to see the static link to the image in the address-bar.
- As I mentioned in the comments: there is no method which is 100% proof simply because the user can download the image and then share it via forums, dropbox etc. All the measures that you'll take will help only to reduce such a behavior - but it cannot be totally eliminated.

Comment: It seems like this solution would leave the URL capable of retrieving the image for users outside the session at least until the cleanup job removes the image.

Comment: @Justin indeed, BUT: assuming the user wants to share the image - he/she can do so without sharing the URL. The more obsessive you are about exposing static links - the more sophisticated you'll get your mechanism: for example, creating a hierarchy of nested temporary folders (which get cleaned every our). Creating these folders with random names, etc.

Comment: Thinking along those lines, if I use and encrypted session, the file names will not be visible in transit over the web, and I could simply use GUIDS for the filenames and then they would only really be practically discover-able if the user intentionally shared them, and then that would be up to them.  However, it doesn't really provide a solution that fits the criteria I requested.  If I don't find a solution that fits my criteria exactly, I will probably do just what you have proposed, or some variant of it.

Comment: @Justin you wrote: "A copy of the image URL should not work after logout" - in case the user actually clicks the "logout" button you can remove the folder/image. But unfortunately, in most cases, the user never logs-out, they simply disconnect which leaves the session hanging until session-timeout is reached.